# Counting values in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What I am looking for is to group by and count the total of different data in the same table and have them show in two different columns. Like below.

Data in table A

Fields:

```
Name    Type  
 Bob    1  
 John   2 
 Bob    1 
 Steve  1 
 John   1 
 Bob    2
```

Desired result from query:

```
Name   Type 1  Type 2
Bob    2       1
John   1       1
Steve  1       0
```

Comment: Yikes, I think that'll depend on the RDMS; not sure it can be done in ANSI SQL.  Which DB is this for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do the trick in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM( CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1,
  SUM( CASE type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type2
FROM
  myTable
GROUP BY
  name
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was writing.

Comment: In SQL Server, you'd use CASE...END statements, there is no IF() syntax.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I wrote it before Adam specified the RDBMS.

Comment: You are so close to being correct. You should remove "type =" from the cases and add an end statement. I'll edit it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the group effort, wiht you answers and MSDN. I got it working thanks.

Comment: Thanks Randolpho, I'm mostly used to MySQL, but glad it's fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

No time to write the code, but the Case statement is what you want here. SImply havea value of 1 if it meets the case and zero if it deosn't. Then you can sum the columns.

Answer (score 0):

@Seb has a good solution, but it's server-dependent. Here's an alternate using subselects that should be portable:

```
select
  name,
  (select count(type) from myTable where type=1 and name=a.name) as type1,
  (select count(type) from myTable where type=2 and name=a.name) as type2
from
  myTable as a
group by 
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate GROUP BY subqueries.

```
SELECT Name, a.Count1, b.Count2
from myTable
JOIN
  (SELECT Name, SUM(Type) AS Count1 FROM myTable GROUP BY Name WHERE Type=1) AS a ON a.Name = myTable.Name
  (SELECT Name, SUM(Type) FROM myTable GROUP BY Name WHERE Type=2) AS b ON b.Name = myTable.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a CrossTab solution. The above solutions will work, but you'll come unstuck if you want a general solution and have N types.

A CrossTab solution will solve this for you. If this is for quickly crunching some numbers then dump your data into Excel and use the native Pivot Table feature.

If it's for a RDBMS in an app, then it depends upon the RDBMS. MS SQL 2005 and above has a crosstab syntax. See:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3521101/Cross-Tab-reports-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm